# How to replace the page loader with the company icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a gif loader to show before page is loading. But I want to show my own company logo with some animation instead of that. 
I have the page_loader div class with the loader.gif image but I want to animate using css

```
.page_loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: url(../img/vierra_loader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```
<div class="page_loader"></div>
```

I want to show my logo animating instead of this readymade loader

Comment: Voted to close as question is too broad. And the posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem

Comment: @phpfranko there is a url in your code and you should just change it, you should know some basic fundamentals before asking questions. thats why you got downvote. (i didn't downvote by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the gif to your logo.png file

Background :url(../images/logo.png)